# What's the modern equivalent of ntsysv?

Tags: rhel, systemd

Back in the old Red Hat days, there's a CUI (curses-based) utility called ntsysv, which lets us see conveniently the services which are enabled by default (at the current runlevel) and lets us enable/disable services. Is there an equivalent today in the systemd-based environment?

Comment: See [this](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/199/Systemd-Graphical-Tools) linux magazine article.

Comment: Thanks. Aside from the GUI tools mentioned in the article, I also found a CUI tool: [chkservice](https://github.com/linuxenko/chkservice).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is [chkservice](https://www.tecmint.com/chkservice-manage-systemd-units-in-terminal/), available in Debian 10 or you can always build from source.

Other GUI-based tools are also available, as pointed out by @meuh.